# Cassandra: How to delete UUIDs from the CLI?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, pelops

Currently I'm using a client ([Pelops](https://github.com/s7/scale7-pelops)) to insert UUIDs (both lexical and time) in to Cassandra. I haven't yet implemented a facility to remove them with Pelops; i'm testing and refining the insertion mechanism.

As such, I would like to use the CLI to delete test UUID values. It seems, however, that I'm unable to delete UUID rowkeys and columns with the `del` command. Is there something I'm missing? I have to use `assume as` to list the rows in column families with UUID row keys, but deleting the displayed row keys does not delete the entries.

I can view columns with UUID values without `assume as` (provided they're not contained in rows with UUID keys), but I am unable to delete them from the CLI as well. Is it not possible to do this from the CLI, or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208104/unable-to-retrieve-data-from-cassandra

Comment: @Schildmeijer: Don't see how that question is related to mine. I know all about the validators (though I haven't used them for my keyspace yet). I'm currently using the "assume" to be able to view the UUID row keys. I just want to know how to delete those UUID row keys from the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered on the mailing list, you need to upgrade to 0.8 to deal with non-string keys using the CLI.